# Mysql set variables invalid after select

Tags: mysql

this is my mysql query script

```
SELECT @num:=@num+1 AS sid, 
        DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(DATE_SUB('2022-04-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL @num DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE
FROM my_table, 
    (SELECT @num:= 0) t
WHERE ADDDATE('2022-04-01', INTERVAL @num DAY) <= DATE_FORMAT('2022-04-08', '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY sid ;
```

when i execute this query, it normally has data.

```
|sid | DATE|
|1|2022-04-01|
|2|2022-04-02|
|3|2022-04-03|
|4|2022-04-04|
|5|2022-04-05|
|6|2022-04-06|
|7|2022-04-07|
|8|2022-04-08|
```

But i execute in my docker mysql.
it's no data.

i set variables `set @num:=0` and query. it has data

but if i query the second time. it no data again.

why in my docker mysql, it must be set variables and just only be executed once and then varialbe will be invalid ?

Comment: what is a docker mysql?

Comment: using docker container run mysql ..

Comment: Ok - I thought that was the case - was not sure